# Unicorn server fails to restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, unicorn

When I add new gems into my application code, and try to deploy it, my unicorn fails to restart. Logfile shows that worker process failed to start because of uninitialized constant. For example last time I have this:

```
I, [2012-11-20T13:01:03.969130 #26750]  INFO -- : executing ["/srv/tutti/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn", "-D", "-c", "/srv/tutti/shared/config/unicorn.rb", "-E", "production", {10=>#<Kgio::UNIXServer:fd 10>}] (in /srv/tutti/releases/20121120125618)
I, [2012-11-20T13:01:03.969539 #26750]  INFO -- : forked child re-executing...
I, [2012-11-20T13:01:05.056841 #26750]  INFO -- : inherited addr=/tmp/unicorn.tutti.sock fd=10
I, [2012-11-20T13:01:05.057480 #26750]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/srv/tutti/releases/20121120125618/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)
<...>
E, [2012-11-20T13:01:09.947747 #21381] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 26750 exit 1> exec()-ed
```

I have `gem "simple_form"` in `/srv/tutti/releases/20121120125618/Gemfile` and if I stop & start instead of sending USR2, it works properly.

Files:

- [config/unicorn.rb](https://gist.github.com/4117920)
- [unicorn_init](https://gist.github.com/4117958)

By the way, removing `preload_app true` and sending HUP signal had the some problem as well.